# How to make image rotation look clean? Android GL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, sprite, mdpi

I am reading the book called beginning android games.

In the book it has the following method in the SpriteBatcher class...

```
public void drawSprite(float x, float y, float width, float height, float angle, TextureRegion region) {
    float halfWidth = width / 2;
    float halfHeight = height / 2;

    float rad = angle * Vector2.TO_RADIANS;
    float cos = FloatMath.cos(rad);
    float sin = FloatMath.sin(rad);

    float x1 = -halfWidth * cos - (-halfHeight) * sin;
    float y1 = -halfWidth * sin + (-halfHeight) * cos;
    float x2 = halfWidth * cos - (-halfHeight) * sin;
    float y2 = halfWidth * sin + (-halfHeight) * cos;
    float x3 = halfWidth * cos - halfHeight * sin;
    float y3 = halfWidth * sin + halfHeight * cos;
    float x4 = -halfWidth * cos - halfHeight * sin;
    float y4 = -halfWidth * sin + halfHeight * cos;

    x1 += x;
    y1 += y;
    x2 += x;
    y2 += y;
    x3 += x;
    y3 += y;
    x4 += x;
    y4 += y;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x3;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y3;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x4;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y4;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

    numSprites++;
}
```

**My question is how do you rotate an image like the one below smoothly so that the lines in the image don't look pixelated?**

I do have the image at the right size and DPI and looks great before its rotated, but when it is rotated the edges of the lines don't look so great.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using LINEAR sampling instead of NEAREST, though it's hard for me to guess more without seeing a picture of the problem, or seeing your texture creation code.

Comment: took a screen shot rather than putting some random image off the internet to relate to...... see how the planes lines are so... crappy?

Comment: Yeah kind of jagged. What kind of sampling are you using, can you put up your texture creation code? Some Antialiasing might help too, though I don't know the code to enable that specifically.

Comment: Where can I read more about linear sampling so that I could apply this? I am not using any particular kind of sampling to my knowledge. The code to the project I am using to learn from is here: http://beginning-android-games.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch09-jumper/

Comment: It's an argument to `glTexParameteri`. Try `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); ` at some point when you have the texture bound.

Comment: Now that I got looking at the texture class from the site I supplied above, I am starting to see what you are talking about. I will keep looking, but was wondering do I need to change anything in the drawSprite() method? here is link again in case you missed it: http://beginning-android-games.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch09-jumper/

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to change anything else. I looked at the code and it's currently using nearest sampling, `GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);setFilters(GL10.GL_NEAREST, GL10.GL_NEAREST);` Try changing the `setFilters` to GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! YOU LITERALLY SAVED ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)   I wish I could give you like a million dollars, I could have never figured this out on my own. You def answered my question! Thanks again!